# How can I customize the non-generic class names in generated Swagger files?

Tags: c#, swagger

I faced with problem with swagger generation of generic type names.
For example I have the following code:

```
public class BulkRequest<T1, T2>
{
    public IEnumerable<Operation<T1, T2>> Operations { get; set; }
}

[ProducesResponseType(typeof(BulkRequest<ClassA, ClassB>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
```

And after Swagger generates some ugly names like: `ClassAClassBBulkRequest` and `ClassAClassBOperation`.

I don't want to change `BulkRequest` class because it used in multiple places in our system.

So do we have any way to generate readable class names with Swagger?

Comment: Most likely your easiest call would be to inherit class filling in generic with concrete types.

public class ConcreteRequest : BulkRequest<int, string> but that requires changes in another places as you've already said.

Comment: @user2184057 thanks! Makes sense to me, but in this case I will still have the same problem with `IEnumerable<Operation<T1, T2>>` type property... any ideas?

Comment: What tool are you using to consume the swagger and generate your client stub?

Comment: @Caius Jard just use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore NuGet and check generated json in browser.

Comment: OK, and what about tools for the other (front) end,  like AutoRest/NSwag..

Comment: @Caius Jard SwaggerUi. But I believe it wont work in the correct way for any tool because generic types in json already generated with these weird names

Comment: But the type names don't go down the wire, so they're essentially renamable/ignorable/irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used `CustomSchemaId` to solve this issue. Maybe it will be useful for someone who is facing a similar problem.

Credit to [an opened issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1803), which pointed me in this direction.

I just added the following `CustomSchemaIds` in Swagger settings:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    // ... 
    c.CustomSchemaIds(i => {
        var typeName = type.Name;
        if (!type.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType) {
            return typeName;
        }

        var genericArgumentIds = type.GetGenericArguments()
            .Select(t => t.Name)
            .ToArray();

        return new StringBuilder(typeName)
            .Replace($"`{genericArgumentIds.Count()}", string.Empty)
            .Append($"<{string.Join(",", genericArgumentIds).TrimEnd(',')}>")
            .ToString();
    });
});
```

And after this, I got type in format that I was looking for:

```
BulkRequest<ClassA,ClassB>
```